# How does Erlang's support for *transparent* distribution of actors impact application design?

Tags: algorithm, erlang, distributed, actor

One of the features of the actor model in Erlang is *transparent distribution*.  Unless I'm misinterpreting, when you send messages between actors, you theoretically shouldn't assume that they are in the same process space or even co-located on the same physical machine.

I've always been under the impression that distributed, fault tolerant systems require careful application design to solve inherent problems around [ordering/causality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clocks) and [consensus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science)) (among others).

I'm pretty sure that Erlang doesn't promise to solve these classes of problems transparently, so my question is, how do Erlang developers cope with this? Do you design your application as if all the actors are in the same process space and then only solve distribution problems when it comes time to actually distribute them?

If so, is this *transparent distribution* feature of Erlang really just concerned with the wire protocol used for remote messaging and not really *transparent* in the sense that a true distributed application still requires careful design in the application layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that erlang does not inherently solve the problems of Ordering/Causality or Consensus. What erlang does abstract for you is the difference between sending messages to local or remote nodes.

I'm not sure it would really be possible to solve those problems in a language design. That more properly belongs in a framework. The OTP framework does have some tools to help with that. Really though it's somewhat dependent on the specific problem you are solving.

For one example of an Erlang VectorClock implementation look at [distributerl](http://code.google.com/p/distributerl/)
Erlang OTP Supervisors also might provide some of the necessary infrastructure for consensus but there is some thought that Consensus is an impossibility in asynchronous message passing distributed systems. See your referenced wiki page for additional information on that.

Answer (score 3):

Erlang does, in fact, solve these problems transparently.  It can do this because it is a functional language with immutable (single-assignment) variables.  It uses the [Actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) for concurrency, and was specifically designed to allow hot-swapping of code and concurrent programming without the programmer having to worry about [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)).

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_programming_language) actually has a pretty good description of this.  It is my understanding that Ericsson invented the language as a practical way to program massively parallel phone switches.

Comment: Re: synchronicity, I was referring to causal relationships and event ordering problems that arise in fault-tolerant distributed systems more so than "data synchronization".  I'll see if I can clarify that part a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Erlang promises those things (http://www.sics.se/~joe/thesis/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf section 3.1 (39-40)):

- Everything is a process.
- Processes are strongly isolated.
- Process creation and destruction is a lightweight operation.
- Message passing is the only way for processes to interact.
- Processes have unique names.
- If you know the name of a process you can send it a message.
- Processes share no resources.
- Error handling is non-local.
- Processes do what they are supposed to do or fail.

and rest is up to you. If you want know why see chapter 2. Shortly, you can send message to process if you know its PID even it is on another piece of HW. You can't be sure if message arrive unless you receive response with common secret. You can be sure that you will receive failure message when process failure when you monitor (or link) it. Those are basic elements with which you can build up what ever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I think it reiterates my point that Erlang's "transparent distribution" is really just "transparent remote messaging".  I agree with @{Jeremy Wall} that there are problems that come up when you distribute systems that can't be solved transparently.  For example, those outlined in this paper:

http://research.sun.com/techrep/1994/smli_tr-94-29.pdf